# Using awk to capture first line of a multiline output?

Tags: bash, scripting, sed, awk, system-administration

I have this output, which is the PID of all processes running matching a grep for fcgi:

```
# ps ax | grep fcgi | cut -f1 -d' '
21065
21066
21067
21068
21069
21070
24801
```

I want to cut out the very first number (i.e. 21065) so I can pass it to the kill function to kill the parent process (the parent process is returned as the first PID).

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

to get the pid number

```
PARENT_PID=`ps ax | grep fcgi | cut -f1 -d' ' | head -1`
```

to directly kill:

```
kill `ps ax | grep fcgi | cut -f1 -d' ' | head -1`
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `ps ax | grep...` to kill a process, if you can avoid it. See [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryUnix%5Cb%29#How_do_I_kill_a_process_by_name.3F__I_need_to_get_the_PID_out_of_ps_aux_.7C_grep_....)

Instead use `pidof`

Comment: Ended up forcing the spawning source to create a PID file. Now, I cat/kill what's in the pidfile.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to jump through [all the hoops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312511/using-awk-to-capture-first-line-of-a-multiline-output/6312528#6312528) of running `ps`, `grep`, `cut`, `head`, and `kill` yourself. That's what `pkill` is for.

```
pkill fcgi
```

Also see `pgrep` for future reference.

Comment: @ripat: `killall` is actually pretty problematic, and should only be used if pkill is NOT available on a given system (OSX for example). On some systems it actually kills everything, on others it does a poor job of matching, and no no case that I know of is it better than pkill.